# windows 10 apps not working when fiddler is closed?

Tags: windows-10, fiddler

I dont know why this error showed to me when Telerik Fiddler is closed in My Labtop, My Instagram and another application like Facebook, Edge (Universal Apps) and ... not working and all of them have internet connection problems. this error always show me in microsoft store:

[image]

But when I open Fiddler application this problem gone and fixed from Windows store and Edge (but instagram and facebook problems not fixed). What is wrong in My Windows?

Comment: Sounds like a dns issue

Comment: yes,i set dns manualy not work, just problem gone when i open fiddler

Comment: Remove proxy from `inetcpl.cpl` >Connections tab > Lan Settings > Proxy Server.

Comment: @Biswa that not work

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler is registering as a local proxy, so that is can capture network traffic from apps. Maybe your proxy settings are broken and Fiddler fixes them?

1. Open the Start menu and search for `proxy`. *Change proxy settings* item will appear, select it.
2. In the settings window toggle *Use a proxy server* to Off.

Comment: ty for answer I checked the proxy setting,My proxy setting is off,When i open fiddler that set "http=127.0.0.1:8888;https=127.0.0.1:8888"
My store works but when proxy is off(fiddler closed) universal apps not working and show me that image error

Comment: Yeah, your internet provider is obviously blocking communication between you and Microsoft the use of a proxy prevents that from happening

Comment: you mean fiddler have a proxy server? I think that is just local proxy not server, Am i wrong?

Comment: @Ramhound That's just Fiddler's local proxy which it sets up to capture traffic. Not internet provider's proxy.